# Cant send E-Mail with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, outlook, scheduled-tasks

I have Task1 - it makes a report in pandas and saves it as excel file. Then i have Task2 which finds saved file and sends it via Outlook to my collegues.
I am using .bat files to make jobs and Windows Task Scheduler to run them.
The problem is - when click on .bat file it sends an email, but when i run it on Scheduler it doesnt send an email

How can i fix this?

Code of Task2:

```
import win32com.client as client
from datetime import datetime
import pathlib

outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)  # 0 is the code for a mail item (see the enumerations)
message.To = '@.com'
message.Subject = 'Report from ' + str(datetime.now().date())
message.Body = 'Report from ' + str(datetime.now().date())
path = pathlib.Path('C:\\Report ' \
                    + str(datetime.now()).split()[0] + '.xlsx')
absolute = str(path.absolute())
message.Attachments.Add(absolute)

message.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`schedule`](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) library in python.

For example, you could run the script or function `function_name` once every day at `hour` o'clock like:

```py
import schedule

schedule.every().day.at(hour).do(function_name)

while True:
     schedule.run_pending()
```